# Jenkins - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile on project

Tags: java, selenium, maven, jenkins

I'm running into the following issue when trying to run my suites on Jenkins.

```
[ERROR]  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project framework: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR]  Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later. 
[ERROR]  Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
```

Everything works locally, including maven install. I've added the source and target in the `pom.xml`, as well as included the top level Maven targets before the execute shell. Jenkins global tools is set to Maven 3.8.1 - however it still returns that the source and target options are no longer supported when running through Jenkins. Am I overlooking something?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>****</groupId>
<artifactId>framework</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <gridUrl>****</gridUrl>
</properties>
<build>

        <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
    

    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.webdriver</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdriver-chrome</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.7376</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.stephenc.monte</groupId>
        <artifactId>monte-screen-recorder</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

[image]

Error log capture:

[image]

Comment: The posted output of the build looks different than the given pom excerpt... they do not belong together....

Comment: There is a 3.1 plugin version in the output, not 3.8.1...

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1744774)

Comment: Note: If you declare properties `<maven.compiler.[source|target]>` you don't have to declare `<build>...<plugin>...maven-compiler-plugin` just for that too. [`compiler:compile` considers those properties by itself.](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#source)

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the logs and the build step. There are 2 steps, 
a maven step: `mvn clean test`,
and a shell step, which also has a `mvn clean test`,
but  can't tell which step the failure relates to as the picture has been cropped. Proper TEXT logs would help showing the step, command and the failure. Also I believe Global Tool Config for maven in not extended to freestyle shell steps,

Answer (score 0):

Read the `-target` option explanation at [The javac Command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/javac.html) and also [JEP 182: Policy for Retiring javac -source and -target Options](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/182).

As noted in the maven-compiler-plugin [Setting the -source and -target of the Java Compiler](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html), just because you can enter a `-source` / `-target` values, does not mean you'll get it.

Since the pom settings don't match the logs (maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 vs 3.8.1), can't say for sure (run [`mvn help:effective-pom`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/usage.html) to understand what's happening), but if you want -source / -target 5, you can't use JDK 8, you can try JDK 7.